# How can I improve my audios using After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

How can I improve my audios using after effects?

Is there any external application that can make the audio more professional and clearer for the listener?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with graphic design.

Comment: This can be ontopic question. Only  assume that some graphical audio visualization is wanted - something more arty than subtitles or oscilloscope.. In Youtube there is plenty of this kind stuff https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeNHHIjgvHU